# How to update a secondary tiles in windows phone 8.1 using database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to update a secondary tile.

I am using sqlite database used to store some data.

I've searched internet over this issues, I got only one solution as XML schema.

But I need to update secondary tiles via database query.

So Is it possible to update it or not.

Please help.. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your `tile's` content through `notifications`.
You will have to query your database and transform the response as an `XML template` that can be rendered by the tile.

Here is a link to the documentation: [Quickstart: Sending a tile update (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868253.aspx).
Note that you will have to call `TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile()` instead of `TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication()` as explained in the link to target the secondary tile.

You can also have a look at this sample : [Secondary tiles sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178) since it provided some helper classes to generate the XML for updating the tiles.

For periodic updates you have two options:

- you can use the `TileUpdateManager.StartPeriodicUpdate` which calls a URI in order to retrive information. See [Periodic notification overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150587.aspx)
- you can write a `background task` in order to update your task. See [Updating App Tile using Background Agent](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/780843/Updating-App-Tile-using-Background-Agent-in-Window) and [Update a live tile from a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj991805.aspx)

I think the better solution for you is the backgruond task.

Comment: I need to update the secondary tile on every midnight.. Is it possible?

Comment: I am confused by position of calling updateTile().. Where I should need to call that method.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my answer with the information for updating your tile periodically.